# Coefficients of Artin L-Function as Dirichlet Series

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given a Galois extension $K /  \mathbb{Q}$ and a character $\chi$ of the Galois group $G=Gal(K /  \mathbb{Q})$ of degree $d \geq 1$, consider the Dirichlet Series expansion $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nn^{-s}$ of the Artin L-Function $L(s, \chi) = \prod_{p \nmid \mathfrak{D}_{K /  \mathbb{Q}}} [\det(I-p^{-s}\chi(\sigma_p))]^{-1}$. I want to show the following:

(1) The sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is multiplicative (that is, $a_{mn}=a_ma_n$ for all pairs of coprime natural numbers $m,n$).

(2) For every integer prime $p$ not dividing the discriminant $\mathfrak{D}_{K /  \mathbb{Q}}$, we have $a_p = \chi(\sigma_p)$ where $\sigma_p$ denotes the usual Frobenius element.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** First assertion is a general fact about Dirichlet series defined by infinite product: if 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \prod_p \left(1+\frac{a_{p,1}}{p^s} + \frac{a_{p,2}}{p^{2s}} + \cdots \right)$$
with $a_{p,i}$ constants. Then $a_{nm} = a_n a_m$ if $(n,m)=1$. 

Second assertion: Denote eigenvalues of $\rho(\sigma_p)$ by $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$, then sole contribution of $a_p$ comes from $$\frac{1}{(1-p^{-s}\lambda_1)\cdots (1-p^{-s}\lambda_n)}$$

Comment: FYI, the function you defined is not the **complete** Artin $L$-series.For complete one, first assertion still holds, but second need not for ramified primes.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot.